# I created a dice cube model using a tutorial and i would like to expoert the subdivision holes as properties to unity3d. how can i do it?

Tags: modeling, export, unity, properties, custom-properties

This is the tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xrzvb8HJV-8&t=2s

This is the model in my blender:

[image: dice model]

in the video tutorial it's on minute 9:31 Extrude Faces Along Normals and then when you press the I key you can extrude the holes for example:
[image: extrude]

I want to be able to control this extrude of each hole in unity3d in the inspector. to change the scale/extrude of each hole just like in the video.

so when I export the model to unity3d it will have also each hole as object or as it should be so I can control each hole scale and other properties.

this is how the dice cube looks like in unity3d after imported it to unity.
in the hierarchy I have the cube object and a light. but I want to have also the holes each hole as object when importing it to unity.

[image: the dice cube model in unity3d]

Comment: Hello, Sharon, welcome!  Not sure if this is a Blender question.. some might think it a Unity question, and so off-topic? But ... let it be, wait and see. Would shape-keys help you out here? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=unFd5a9-Ga8

Comment: The problem is with the object in Blender it is easy to control the "holes", as each hole is basically just a quad face which is moved out or in. The rounding and smoothing comes from the _Subdivision Surface_ modifier, but this is applied to convert  the visible geometry to a real mesh when you export the object for _Unity_. Which means, the holes are no longer simple quad faces, but many faces forming the smoothed holes and therefore more complicated to control. Unfortunately you cannot use shapekeys for moving the faces in and out and then apply the _Subdivision Surface_ modifier.

Comment: As Gordon explains, there is no way to do this with as simple of a control as you do with a simple mesh with a subdiv modifier on top. I'm curious though, in which situation would you even need to be able to control a dice's hole extrusion and size in a game engine?

Comment: @L0Lock just thought to make it animated maybe the dice cube.